# I left porkchops out to thaw over night can i cook them still

Tags: pork-chops

I i left porkchops out to thaw i forgotten about them and left them out all night is it ok to cook still

Comment: I have accidentally done this before and I have lived to tell the tale. YMMV. Just be sure to cook it very well.

Comment: Please do not advise people with anecdotal experiences that suggest food safety protocol can be taken lightly.  It could be quite dangerous.  These pork chops should be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

The USDA suggests not leaving any meat out in the open for more than two hours. Any meat left too long in temperatures between 40 and 140 degrees Fahrenheit may rapidly develop bacteria.